# Unknown entity: JPA Procedure execution

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure using hibernate jpa implementation, but I'm getting an error because **Hierarchy.class** is not an entity but I'm not allowed to create the table in the db. Is there a way to use it only to retrieve the results mapped without creating the table?

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL prc_hrGetHierarchyList(:Emp)")
                .addEntity(Hierarchy.class)
                .setParameter("Emp", employeeNumber);
```

Exception:

```
Unknown entity: model.hris.Hierarchy
```

Comment: Did you tried using @MappedSuperClass?

Comment: I just tried and it is still failing in the same line with the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That addEntity method always expects entity class only.You can get it done by other way.

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = (SQLQuery)  session.createSQLQuery("CALL prc_hrGetHierarchyList(:Emp)").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Hierarchy.class));
sqlQuery.addScalar("your column Name", StringType.INSTANCE);
sqlQuery.addScalar("your column Name", DoubleType.INSTANCE);
return sqlQuery.list();
```

Comment: I'll try this and I'm going to come back with the results

Comment: Didn't work as it is but helped to generate a solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the that you're using `javax.persistence.Entity` to annotate your entity beans. This could happen if you import `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`
- You can use `callableStatement` to get this done.

  ```
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();         

  CallableStatement  callableStatement = session.connection().prepareCall("{prc_hrGetHierarchyList(?)}");    
  callableStatement.setInt(1, employeeNumber);    
  callableStatement.execute();
  resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet(); 

  while(resultSet.next()){
     System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
  }
  ```

Comment: Yes I'm using `javax.persistence.Entity`, I want to have the resultset automatically mapped to a list of objects I don't want to manually read the resultset and assign every property